# Infinite scroll with AngularJs and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, infinite-scroll

How do you implement infinite scroll on data that you get from firebase. So far I found an angularjs [directive](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html), that works really great but I'm having difficulty implementing it with fireable as firebase returns all data in one single request and this is not what I want.

Comment: If there is no way to paginate data in Firebase then there's no point to an infinite scroll. But somehow I have trouble believing that there's no pagination functionality - have you searched their API documentation?

Comment: Actually, it is *exactly* pagination. :) http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/yumaB/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Few weeks ago, I made a JS function that allowed an infinite scrolling in [my app](https://venezuela.firebaseapp.com/).

First, a set of data is displayed when the user visit the website:

```
// Add a callback that is triggered for each message.
var n = 25; // Step size for messages display.
$(window).load(function() {
lastMessagesQuery = messagesRef.limit(n); 
lastMessagesQuery.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  var message = snapshot.val();
  $('<div/>').text(message.text).prependTo($('#messagesDiv'));
  $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
});
$('#messagesDiv').fadeTo(1000, 1);
});
```

Then, the function that makes possible the infinite scrolling:

```
// Pagination.
var i = 0; // Record variable.
function moreMessages () { 
i += n; // Record pagination updates. 
moreMessagesQuery = messagesRef; // Firebase reference.
moreMessagesQuery.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.exportVal(); // Fetch all data from Firebase as an Object.
  var keys = Object.keys(data).reverse(); // Due to the Keys are ordered from the oldest to the newest, it nessesary to change its sequence in order to display Firebase data snapshots properly.
  var total_keys = Object.keys(data).length;
  var k = keys[i]; // Key from where to start counting. Be careful what Key you pick.
  if (i < total_keys) { // Stop displaying messages when it reach the last one.
    lastMessagesQuery = messagesRef.endAt(null, k).limit(n); // Messages from a Key to the oldest.
    lastMessagesQuery.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      var message = snapshot.val();
      $('<div/>').text(message.text).appendTo($('#messagesDiv')).hide().fadeIn(1000); // Add set of messages (from the oldest to the newest) at the end of #messagesDiv.
    });
  }  
});
}
```

Finally, the infinite scrolling:

```
// Load more messages when scroll reach the bottom.
$(window).scroll(function() { 
if (window.scrollY == document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
  moreMessages();
}  
});
```

It works great with small data sets. I hope this helps you to solve your problem (or gives you more ideas).

---

**UPDATE October 2015**

Firebase has growth since my original response, which means now it's pretty easy to achieve an infinite scrolling just using its [Javascript API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/):

First, I recommend to [create an Index](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html#section-indexing-order-by-child) in your Firebase. For this answer, I create this one:

```
{
   "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false,
      "messages": {
         ".indexOn": "id"
      }
   }
}
```

Then, let's make some magic with Firebase:

```
// @fb: your Firebase.
// @data: messages, users, products... the dataset you want to do something with.
// @_start: min ID where you want to start fetching your data.
// @_end: max ID where you want to start fetching your data.
// @_n: Step size. In other words, how much data you want to fetch from Firebase.
var fb = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/');
var data = [];
var _start = 0;
var _end = 9;
var _n = 10;
var getDataset = function() {
   fb.orderByChild('id').startAt(_start).endAt(_end).limitToLast(_n).on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
      data.push(dataSnapshot.val());
   });
   _start = _start + _n;
   _end = _end + _n;
}
```

Finally, a better *Infinite Scrolling* (without jQuery):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY === document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
     getDataset();
  } 
});
```

I'm using this approach with [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and it's blazing fast no matter how big your data is.

Comment: Where do you add the infinite scrolling? Nothing happens for me when I scroll

Comment: @JohnAndrews I add it in my main JS file. If you're using React, just look at this example: https://github.com/heartyrobot/brands/blob/master/src/js/app.js#L56 (BTW, you need to display `data` in order to make things happens.)

Comment: that means registering an `on` listener every time `getDataSet()` is called... is that reasonable? and it only works if you want an ascending order.

Comment: also, if a child is added to an already loaded page, your code pushes it to the end of the list instead of inserting it at its right place

Comment: You are right @antoine129, my code only works in ascending order, but that depends entirely of your requirements. You could easily reverse ```data``` Array to meet your needs... something like ```var _data = data.reverse()``` or using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @Jobsamuel This is an amazing implementation.I am trying to do the exact same using angular 2 with Observable, which looks like 

getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}.json`).map((res: Response) => {
    this.data = res.json();
    return this.data;
    });
  }

but using that I am unable to implement, typescript keeps saying there is no OrderByChild property, could you please tell me how you would do it in Angular 2.

Thank you