# Firebase - get data from child x to child y

Tags: jquery, firebase

I didn't find a way to get the data from child x to child y.

for example:

```
parent:
    child1: {...}
    child2: {...}
    child3: {...}
    child4: {...}
```

get data between child2 to child3.

I know I can get all the first three children, and then remove the first child.

But what if I need the data between child100 to child 101?

This is firebase documentation for retrieving data:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

I didn't see something like what I need in the documentation above.

He did it by getting all the data and remove the data you don't want:

[Infinite scroll with AngularJs and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868604/infinite-scroll-with-angularjs-and-firebase)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `startAt()` and `endAt()`? Those are on the documentation page you linked.

Comment: I will try it... Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an answer @AnidMonsur! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has support for several different [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries), including `startAt()` and `endAt()`, which should suit your needs.

```
var parentRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>/parent");

parentRef.orderByKey().startAt("child100").endAt("child101").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  // This will be called each time for child100, child101, and any nodes between them.
});
```