# Firebase RecyclerView infinite scroll

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

I'm looking for a way to implement infinite scrolling in my `Firebase` app.

**I'm retrieving my data the following way :**

I have a list of keys (items a user created, items a user liked and stuff like this) that I am sending to an adapter which gets the data like this :

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final BaseViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    DatabaseReference ref = getAllItemsRef().child(itemIDs.get(position));

    ValueEventListener itemListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Item item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
            viewHolder.bindItem(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    };
    ref.addValueEventListener(itemListener);

}
```

I would like to add infinite scrolling to gain performance but I have no idea how I should do that with `Firebase`.

I've seen that `FirebaseUI` would like to implement it but haven't done it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite scroll with AngularJs and Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868604/infinite-scroll-with-angularjs-and-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simply achievable with a combination of startAt, limitToLast and orderByKey/orderByChild