# How to trigger a Firebase POST request when a Button is clicked in Node.js / EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**EDIT:**

There were actually still some issues. The real problem was actually the Firebase security rules. All was solved here : [How to put a Node.js variable inside my <script></script>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408945/how-to-put-a-node-js-variable-inside-my-script-script)

**QUESTION:**

How to trigger a Firebase POST request when "UpvoteButton" or "DownvoteButton" is clicked ?

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

**UPDATE 4:**

I think I am making progress. Find the updated code below. Now I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in ... while compiling ejs
```

CODE:

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>

<% var config = { %>
<%    apiKey: "info", %>
<%    authDomain: "info", %>
<%    databaseURL: "info", %>
<%    storageBucket: "info", %>
<%    messagingSenderId: "info" %>
<% }; %>
<% firebase.initializeApp(config); %>

</script>

<div class ="containerMarginsDetails">

    <h1 class= "detailsTitle"><%=post.title %></h1>
    <div class="row">
        <img class = "postImg"  src="/images/uploads/<%= post.image %>">
        <span class="UpvoteButton"> </span><span class="DownvoteButton"> </span> <span class="HP"><%= post.upvotes - post.downvotes%> HP</span>
    </div>

</div>

<script> 

    <% var upvotesRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/section/"+id+"/upvotes"); %>
    <% var downvotesRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/section/"+id+"/downvotes"); %>

    $('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
        <% if(authdata == null) { %>
            window.location.href = "/users/login";
        <% } else { %>

            var $this = $(this);
            var $other = $('.DownvoteButton');

            if ($this.hasClass("on")) {
                $this.removeClass("on");

                <%  upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) { %> 
                <%  if (!upvotes) { %>
                <%    upvotes = 0; %>
                <%   } %>
                <%   upvotes = upvotes - 1; %>
                <%   return upvotes; %>
                <%  }); %>

            } else if (!$this.hasClass('on') && $other.hasClass("on")) {
                $this.addClass('on');
                $other.removeClass("on");

                <%  upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) { %>
                <%   if (!upvotes) { %>
                <%     upvotes = 0; %>
                <%   } %>
                <%   upvotes = upvotes + 1; %>
                <%   return upvotes; %>
                <% }); %>

                <% downvotesRef.transaction(function (downvotes) { %>
                <%  if (!upvotes) { %>
                <%    downvotes = 0; %>
                <%  } %>
                <%  downvotes = downvotes - 1; %>
                <%  return downvotes; %>
                <% }); %>

            } else {
                $this.addClass('on');

                <% upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) { %>
                <%  if (!upvotes) { %>
                <%    upvotes = 0; %>
                <%  } %>
                <%  upvotes = upvotes + 1; %>
                <%  return upvotes; %>
                <% }); %>
            } 
        <% } %>
    });

    $('.DownvoteButton').click(function () {
        <% if(authdata == null) { %>
            window.location.href = "/users/login";
        <% } else { %>
            var $this = $(this);
            var $other = $('.UpvoteButton');
            if ($this.hasClass("on")) {
                $this.removeClass("on");
            } else if (!$this.hasClass('on') && $other.hasClass("on")) {
                $this.addClass('on');
                $other.removeClass("on");
            } else {
                $this.addClass('on');
            }
        <% } %>
    });

</script>

<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Did you try use firebase browser sdk? It would save your data without explicit http request. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @VladimirGabrielyan That's what I am using (I think). I am not sure I understand what you mean :)

Comment: Saying trigger Firebase Post request you mean save or update something in the database?

Comment: I mean save and update. Set the new data at the desired path.

Comment: Okay then, do all that operations using firebase sdk,use link I meantioned above. Using firebase sdk you can do all manipulations with firebase database(create,read, update delete)

Comment: @VladimirGabrielyan I certainly don't understand what you are suggesting. I am already using the Firebase SDK, but how can I trigger a Firebase request on click ?

Comment: @VladimirGabrielyan Talk is cheap, show me the code :P

Comment: maybe you are missing <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js'></script> on the top of your index.ejs file?

Comment: @VladimirGabrielyan That was not it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to keep all the code in plain javascript between the `<script></script>` tags and initialise firebase also in my ejs file.

The problem was really about Firebase security rules.

Find the detailed answer here: [How to put a Node.js variable inside my <script></script>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408945/how-to-put-a-node-js-variable-inside-my-script-script)

CODE:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "info",
    authDomain: "info",
    databaseURL: "info",
    storageBucket: "info",
    messagingSenderId: "info"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<div class ="containerMarginsDetails">

    <h1 class= "detailsTitle"><%=post.title %></h1>
    <div class="row">
        <img class = "postImg"  src="/images/uploads/<%= post.image %>">
        <span class="UpvoteButton"> </span><span class="DownvoteButton"> </span> <span class="HP"><%= post.upvotes - post.downvotes%> HP</span>
    </div>

</div>

<script>

        var upvotesRef =  firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/<%=id%>/upvotes");
        var downvotesRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/<%=id%>/downvotes");

        $('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {

                      upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) {  
                       if (!upvotes) { 
                          upvotes = 0; 
                       } 
                         upvotes = upvotes - 1; 
                         return upvotes; 
                      }); 
       });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize firebase by calling `firebase.initializeApp(...)`

Just like firebase guides tell us to:

`

```
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
      authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
      databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
      storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>`
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything. It would have been strange to have to initialise firebase twice anyway, but thx for trying to help :) Have an upvote.