# Firebase, how do I return a handle so that I can call removeObserver?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my observe event code:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            let query = databaseRef.child("palettes").queryOrdered(byChild: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserTypeState")!).queryEqual(toValue: modifiedColor.hexValue())
            // Change the value to the value of the color.

            query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let URL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "URL").value as! String
                self.URLArrayString.append(URL)

                self.collectionView?.reloadData() //Reloads data after the number and all the URLs are fetched
                self.noResultsLabel.isHidden = true
            })
```

How do I retrieve the handle when that particular observer is called so that I can remove it when viewDidDissapear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`observe`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-observeeventtypewithblock) it returns a handle to the registered observer.

You pass this handle to `removeObserverWithHandle()` to remove the observer.

```
let handle = query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    ....
})
```

And then:

```
query.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
```

Comment: Hello ! I tried to ping you before, but I am not sure I did it correctly. So here is the message I wanted to send you: would you know by any chance the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223230/how-to-trigger-a-firebase-request-when-button-is-clicked ?

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 3 I am using

```
 deinit {
 refName.removeAllObserver()
 }
```

where refName is your reference name.

there is also another option, to use:

```
private var updatedMessageRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
...
...
deinit {
if let refHandle = newMessageRefHandle {
messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
}
if let refHandle = updatedMessageRefHandle {
messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
}}
```

but in second case you will have to describe the refHandle in the code.