# With Firebase, Swift removeObserver(withHandle does not remove the observer

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With removeObserver(withHandle in Swift 3, the Observer is not removed on viewDidDisappear

```
var query = FIRDatabaseQuery()

var postRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var postRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    postRef = baseRef.child("Posts")
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    if postRefHandle != nil {
        //try 1:
        //postRef.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle!)

        //try 2:
        //postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "sortTimestamp").removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle!)

        //try 3: 
        //query.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle!)
    }
    //try 4:
    //postRef.removeAllObservers() //works
}

func getPosts()
{
    var count = 20 

    query = postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "sortTimestamp")

    postRefHandle = query.queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(count)).observe(.childAdded //etc.
}
```

So I tried the three methods in viewDidDisappear, but the observer is not removed. 
try 3 query.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle!) as by answer from [Firebase, how do I return a handle so that I can call removeObserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346533/firebase-how-do-i-return-a-handle-so-that-i-can-call-removeobserver) by frank-van-puffelen

The only one that does work is the one outlined in try 4. 
Any reason why I cannot remove the Observer with removeObserver(withHandle? (try 1 - 3)

Also "query.queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(count)).observe(.childAdded"  does not get the latest data from Firebase. I was under the impression the observe always gets the updated data, as opposed to observeSingleEvent. Why does it not do that?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with `postRefHandle`.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman What do you mean? In what way could there be something wrong with the handle?

Comment: Perhaps it is `nil` and the whole `if` block isn't being executed. Try printing something in the block.

Comment: @ArchieGertsmanno the handle is not nil (is printing), so the block should execute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the following code:

```
var postsRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var postRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
var query = FIRDatabaseQuery()

func addHandler() {

    self.postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
    var count = 20
    self.query = self.postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "sortTimestamp")

    self.postRefHandle = self.query.queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(count)).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot) 
    })
}
```

and at a later time you do this function

```
self.postsRef.removeObserver(withHandle: self.postRefHandle!)
```

It removes the observer. This is tested code.

To the second part of your question: querySingleEvent and observe do the same thing data wise but have different behaviors. They will both always get current data - modified by startAt, endAt, equalTo etc.

> observeSingleEvent returns the data, does NOT leave an observer so you
>   will not be notified if that data changes
>
> observe returns the data and leaves an observer attached to the node
>   and will notify you of future changes.

.childAdded:  when any children are added to the node
.childChanges: when any children change in the node
.childRemoved: when a child is removed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I did put in the question that I tried that with         //try 3: 
//query.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle!)

Comment: @PeterdeVries Well, I spoke too soon and incorrectly so I updated my answer with tested code.

Comment: Somehow it fully works when in the addHandler() block itself, it seems to work when I put it in viewDidDisappear (checking in viewDidAppear for the postRefHandle doesn't print). If I come back to the VC and access a different ref, somehow it still triggers the postRef (prints something that shouldn't be printed). It doesn't do that when I use postRef.removeAllObservers(). But it works so far. The second part of my question. you are absolute right, my problem was the timing of viewDidDisappear and viewDidLoad while coming back in the VC. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How I'm Able to Achieve this is by removing child reference.

`var recentRef: FIRDatabaseReference!`

```
recentRef.child("\(groupId)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    recentRef.removeAllObservers() // not_working
                    recentRef.child("\(groupId)").removeAllObservers() //working

                    if let obj = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            //... code here
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without making a query also(Swift 4) -
This removes the reference of the observer properly and works for me.

```
    private let ref = Database.database().reference().child("classTalks")
    private var refHandle: DatabaseHandle!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear()

        refHandle = ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
            ...
        })

    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
        super.viewWillDisappear()

        ref.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
    
    }
```