# How to put a Node.js variable inside my <script></script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase

**PROBLEM:**

I have some Firebase code in a script tag, but it doesn't execute. How should I write my <%=id%> variable in it ?

Normally, when I click the button, a request should be fired to update the upvote value in Firebase, but nothing happens.

The code doesn't execute but I get no errors.

---

**CODE:**

file.ejs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "info",
    authDomain: "info",
    databaseURL: "info",
    storageBucket: "info",
    messagingSenderId: "info"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<div class ="containerMarginsDetails">

    <h1 class= "detailsTitle"><%=post.title %></h1>
    <div class="row">
        <img class = "postImg"  src="/images/uploads/<%= post.image %>">
        <span class="UpvoteButton"> </span><span class="DownvoteButton"> </span> <span class="HP"><%= post.upvotes - post.downvotes%> HP</span>
    </div>

</div>

<script>

        var upvotesRef =  firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/<%=id%>/upvotes");
        var downvotesRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/<%=id%>/downvotes");

        $('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {

                      upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) {  
                       if (!upvotes) { 
                          upvotes = 0; 
                       } 
                         upvotes = upvotes - 1; 
                         return upvotes; 
                      }); 
       });

</script>
```

---

Here is the router file.

file.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var firebase = require("firebase");

router.get('/details/:id', function(req, res){
    global.page_name = "fun";
    var id = req.params.id;
    var funPostRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/"+id);

    funPostRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
        var funPost = snapshot.val();
        res.render('fun/details', {post: funPost, id:id});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

N.B.: Firebase is also initialised in my app.js file.

**EDIT:**

If I try this version of the code, the firebase request is triggered every time I reload the page, not when I click. How can I make sure it is triggered only when I click ?

```
<% var upvotesRef =  firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/"+id+"/upvotes");
var downvotesRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/"+id+"/downvotes"); %>

$('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
      <% upvotesRef.transaction(function (upvotes) {  
          if (!upvotes) { 
             upvotes = 0; 
          } 
             upvotes = upvotes + 1; 
             return upvotes; 
      }); %>
   });
```

**EDIT 2:**

Found the error ! What does it mean ?

[image]

This is very weird since I am authenticated when I click the button and these are my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

I also get the following (non crashing) error message before:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

**EDIT 4:**

If I change my rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

The button works perfectly !

**But how come the code doesn't work with the previous rule although I am authenticated ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a templating language you don't need the `+` operators:

```
var upvotesRef =  firebase.database().ref("posts/fun/<%=id%>/upvotes");
```

Comment: I tried that. Sadly it did not change anything :/ (That's why I went as far as trying the ""+var+"" notation used normally for String concatenation).

Comment: What is so confusing is that I don't get any error message :(

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the source code generated by the templating language and make sure it looks valid. Then I'd add console.log statements all over the place to see what code is and isn't getting called.

Comment: I looked at the source code generated, its all fine. As for console.logs, they don't print anything unless I write them like this: `<% console.log(something) %>` Btw: I updated my question with something I tried where the code does execute, but then I am stuck with no way to execute it only on click (Jquery being client-side, and the firebase func being server side). What would you recommend doing ? It seems only code between `<% %>` is getting executed.

Comment: I was able to do console.logs and I found the error >:) I updated my question with a screenshot. What does the error mean ?

Comment: All right, it was an issue with Firebase rules. I think it's a bug (or I have done something wrong). Permission was denied although I was authenticated. What could cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to "echo" the id with <%- id %>

sadly I can not comment (not enough rep) otherwise I would have asked if you see the id if you inspect the button.

Comment: I tried your notation, but I must have done something wrong since nothing prints to my terminal concerning id. I must also point out that all console.log statements I tried to put between my script tags do not print to my terminal.

Comment: Nonetheless, I am able to print id by writing <% console.log(id) %>. It's there.

Comment: but the console.log prints on the server side right ?

Comment: what if you write it into a script tag and <%= console.log(id) %>

Comment: the id prints on my terminal (server side) when I write: <% console.log(id) %>